# OpenAI GPT-3 API: How to parse the response into an ordered list or dictionary?

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3

GPT-3 is amazing, but parsing its results is a bit of a headache, or I'm missing something here?
For example, I'm asking GPT-3 to write something about "digital marketing" and it's returning back some interesting stuff:

```
\n\n1. Topic: The Benefits of Digital Marketing \nHeadlines: \na. Unlocking the 
Potential of Digital Marketing \nb. Harnessing the Power of Digital Marketing for 
Your Business \nc. How to Maximize Your Return on Investment with Digital Marketing 
\nd. Exploring the Benefits of a Comprehensive Digital Marketing Strategy \ne. 
Leveraging Technology to Take Your Business to the Next Level with Digital Marketing  
\n\n2. Topic: Social Media Strategies for Effective Digital Marketing  \nHeadlines:  
\na. Crafting an Engaging Social Media Presence for Maximum Impact \nb. How to Reach 
and Engage Your Target Audience Through Social Media Platforms  \nc. Optimizing Your 
Content Strategy for Maximum Reach on Social Media Platforms   \nd. Utilizing Paid 
Advertising Strategies on Social Media Platforms   \t\t\t\t\t\t\t     e .Analyzing 
and Improving Performance Across Multiple Social Networks\n\n3. Topic: SEO Best 
Practices for Effective Digital Marketing    Headlines:     a .Understanding Search 
Engine Algorithms and Optimizing Content Accordingly    b .Developing an Effective 
SEO Strategy That Delivers Results c .Leveraging Keywords and Metadata For Maximum 
Visibility d .Exploring Advanced SEO Techniques To Increase Traffic e .Analyzing 
Performance Data To Improve Rankings\n\n4Topic : Email Campaigns For Successful 
Digital Marketin g Headlines : a .Creating Compelling Email Campaigns That Drive 
Results b .Optimizing Email Deliverability For Maximum Impact c .Utilizing Automation 
Tools To Streamline Email Campaign Management d .Measuring Performance And Analyzing 
Data From Email Campaigns e .Exploring Creative Ways To Increase Open Rates On 
Emails\n\n5Topic : Mobile Advertising Strategies For Effective Digita l Marketin g 
Headlines : a ..Maximizing Reach With Mobile Ads b ..Understanding User Behavior On 
Mobile Devices c ..Optimizing Ads For Different Screen Sizes d ..Leveraging Location- 
Based Targeting To Increase Relevance e ..Analyzing Performance Data From Mobile Ads
```

As you can see, it's sent me back a list of topics related to "digital marketing" with some headlines (apparently from a to e). I see some line breaks and tabulation here and there. So my first reflex was to split the text on the line breaks, but it looks like the format is not equal everywhere, as there are very few line breaks in the second half of the response (which make it inaccurate).
What I'd like to do, is reformatting the output, so I can have a kind of list of topics and headlines. Something like this:

```
[
     {"Topic 1": ["headline 1", "headline 2","..."]},
     {"Topic 2": ["headline 1", "headline 2","..."]},
     {"Topic 3": ["headline 1", "headline 2","..."]}
]
```

Maybe there is a parameter to send over withing my request, but I didn't find anything in the doc. So I guess my best bet is to reformat using `regex`. Here I see a pattern `Topic:`and `Headlines:` but it's not always the case. What is consistent is the number prefixing each element `(like Ì., II., 1., 2. or a., b.)` but sometimes it looks like `a ..` (you can see that at the end of the response for example.

Any idea how to do that? (I'm using python for that, but can adapt from another language)

Comment: chatGPT is still very volatile so anything you write today to parse that kind of output may not work tomorrow

Comment: ok, that's my thoughts too @Pingu, any idea how to parse with regex thinks like 1., 2., a., b., I., II. ...?

Comment: Maybe you could ask ChatGPT for JSON output?

Comment: it's not sending it back in JSON

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: ChatGPT has no API yet, so whatever you're doing here, it ain't ChatGPT.

Answer (score 2):

You can get GPT to provide the response in JSON format you just need to train it as part of the prompt. Here is an example prompt:

Provide a list of 3 topics related to climate change and for each topic provide 3 headlines.

Your response should be in JSON format. Here is the expected JSON format:

```
    [
     {"Topic 1": ["headline 1", "headline 2","..."]},
     {"Topic 2": ["headline 1", "headline 2","..."]},
     {"Topic 3": ["headline 1", "headline 2","..."]}
]
```

END PROMPT

You might have to play around with the prompt a little bit, but I have been successful in building email parsers that return the responses in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

All [Edits API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/edit-models-endpoint) endpoints are deprecated.

[image: Screenshot]

Recommended replacements:

- Use `gpt-4` instead of `text-davinci-edit-001` and `code-davinci-edit-001`.
- Use `/v1/chat/completions` instead of `/v1/edits`.

---

##### Use the [Edits endpoint](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/edits)

If you run `test.py` the OpenAI API will return the following completion:

```
1. Topic: The Benefits of Digital Marketing 
Headlines: 

* Unlocking the Potential of Digital Marketing 
* Harnessing the Power of Digital Marketing for Your Business 
* How to Maximize Your Return on Investment with Digital Marketing 
* Exploring the Benefits of a Comprehensive Digital Marketing Strategy 
* Leveraging Technology to Take Your Business to the Next Level with Digital Marketing
```

**test.py**

```
import openai

openai.api_key = '<OPENAI_API_KEY>'

response = openai.Edit.create(
  model = 'text-davinci-edit-001',
  input = '\n\n1. Topic: The Benefits of Digital Marketing \nHeadlines: \na. Unlocking the Potential of Digital Marketing \nb. Harnessing the Power of Digital Marketing for Your Business \nc. How to Maximize Your Return on Investment with Digital Marketing \nd. Exploring the Benefits of a Comprehensive Digital Marketing Strategy \ne. Leveraging Technology to Take Your Business to the Next Level with Digital Marketing',
  instruction = 'Make this readable'
)

content = response['choices'][0]['text']

print(content)
```